# Execute a SProc from within a Sproc (using params passed in)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Does anyone know of a way to execute a stored procedure from within a stored procudure using some of the params passed in from the original procedure.

i.e.
if i pass in params @id, @event date, @ log into sproc 1
then sproc 1 will do it's own stuff and pass in @log and @event_date to sproc 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just execute the second sp the same way you would have from a query.

```
EXEC SPROC2 @LOG, @EVENT_DATE
```

Answer (score 3):

just call:

`exec mysproc @param1 @param2`

inside your sproc.

Answer (score 2):

call exec with the parameters of interest:

```
  ... within sp_1
  ... other code
  exec sp_2 @log, @event_date
```